# How to use faces to enhance text

Tags: faces, font-lock

I'm writing some very simple code to get data from a web api, i then parse the response and output the result in a buffer.

By default this text is very flat, how can i add keyword highlighting that follows the current theme's colourscheme?

For example, the text in the buffer:

Title

- Keyword1: data1
- Keyword2: data2

How can i define, and most importantly apply faces(i think) to the keywords?

Comment: See the Elisp manual (`C-h i`), node [Font Lock Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`propertize` method](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html#Changing-Properties) for that.

For exemple, in your case, to use the `font-lock-builtin-face` on the `Keyword` words, you can do:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^Keyword[0-9]:" nil t)
      (replace-match (propertize (match-string 0) 'face 'font-lock-builtin-face))))
```